# Why the ExceptionInInitializerError here?

Tags: java, exception, static

Note that i know the rules regarding

> ExceptionInInitializerErrors

*it says: Any
exception thrown in a static block is wrapped into
**ExceptionInInitializerError** and then that **ExceptionInInitializerError** is thrown.*
But my question is:  **why**

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

**its thrown here** ?**

```
class AX {
    static int[] x = new int[0];
    static {
       x[0] = 10;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args){
       AX ax = new AX();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates an array with capacity 0:

> ```
> static int[] x = new int[0];
> ```

This assigns value to the first element of `x`:

> ```
> static {
>     x[0] = 10;
> }
> ```

Unfortunately, as seen earlier, the capacity of `x` is 0, it cannot have any elements at all. That's why you get `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

And if you take a closer look at the stack trace,
it sheds more light, as there should be a line like this:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
> ```

That number 0 is the array index that was out of bounds:
index 0 is out of bounds if the array cannot contain any elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is the *cause* of the `ExceptionInInitializerError` exception. What you actually get is:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> > Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

From the docs of [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html):

> As of release 1.4, this exception has been retrofitted to conform to the general purpose exception-chaining mechanism. The "saved throwable object" that may be provided at construction time and accessed via the getException() method is now known as the cause, and may be accessed via the Throwable.getCause() method, as well as the aforementioned "legacy method."

To demonstrate the quote:

```
class X {
    static int[] x = new int[0];
    static {
        x[0] = 10;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // try catch an error for demoing purposes
        try {
            X ax = new X();
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> class java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0